# Closed form of $\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{(n-k)!}{(k+1) (2 n -k +2)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

Can be this sum written in a closed form?
$$\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{(n-k)!}{(k+1) (2 n -k +2)!}$$
In closed form I mean special numbers too (such as Stirling or Harmonic numbers), but independent of $k$?

Comment: `Maple 2020.1` with help of `Mathematica 12.1`  give me:$$-\frac{3 \, _3F_2\left(1,n+2,n+\frac{5}{2};n+3,n+3;4\right)}{(n+2) \Gamma (n+3)}-\frac{i \pi ^{3/2} 2^{-2 n-3}}{\Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{5}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: If we denote this by $A_n$, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {n!}A_{n-1}x^n=\int_0^1\frac{-\log(1-xt)}{1-xt(1-t)}\,dt.$$